# localhost:8080/solr/browse gives a lazy loading error

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr, lucene

I'm new to Solr, just installed Tomcat6 and Solr 3.6.1 on CentOS. I managed to add some data from my MySQL table and use the exampledoc's xml with `http://localhost:8080/solr/update` to populate the index with sample data. I am using an edited version of `solrconfig.xml` from the `examplesdoc`

**Problem:** When I go to the Browse Interface at `http://localhost:8080/solr/browse`, I get the following error in the log file. I do not understand why the error occurs, any ideas how I can fix this?

**Error:**

```
Aug 16, 2012 11:01:56 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/browse params={} hits=254 status=0 QTime=4 
Aug 16, 2012 11:01:56 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: lazy loading error
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$LazyQueryResponseWriterWrapper.getWrappedWriter(SolrCore.java:1763)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$LazyQueryResponseWriterWrapper.getContentType(SolrCore.java:1778)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.writeResponse(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'sol
```

In my **solrconfig.xml**, I have the `/browse` request handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

   <!-- VelocityResponseWriter settings -->
   <str name="wt">velocity</str>

   <str name="v.template">browse</str>
   <str name="v.layout">layout</str>
   <str name="title">Solritas</str>

   <str name="df">text</str>
   <str name="defType">edismax</str>
   <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
   <str name="rows">10</str>
   <str name="fl">*,score</str>
   <str name="mlt.qf">
     text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
   </str>
   <str name="mlt.fl">text,features,name,sku,id,manu,cat</str>
   <int name="mlt.count">3</int>

   <str name="qf">
      text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
   </str>

   <str name="facet">on</str>
   <str name="facet.field">cat</str>
   <str name="facet.field">manu_exact</str>
   <str name="facet.query">ipod</str>
   <str name="facet.query">GB</str>
   <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
   <str name="facet.pivot">cat,inStock</str>
   <str name="facet.range.other">after</str>
   <str name="facet.range">price</str>
   <int name="f.price.facet.range.start">0</int>
   <int name="f.price.facet.range.end">600</int>
   <int name="f.price.facet.range.gap">50</int>
   <str name="facet.range">popularity</str>
   <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.start">0</int>
   <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.end">10</int>
   <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.gap">3</int>
   <str name="facet.range">manufacturedate_dt</str>
   <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.start">NOW/YEAR-10YEARS</str>
   <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.end">NOW</str>
   <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.gap">+1YEAR</str>
   <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">before</str>
   <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">after</str>


   <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
   <str name="hl">on</str>
   <str name="hl.fl">text features name</str>
   <str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0</str>
   <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name</str>
 </lst>
 <arr name="last-components">
   <str>spellcheck</str>
 </arr>
 <!--
 <str name="url-scheme">httpx</str>
 -->
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like missing library to me.

Check out http://wiki.apache.org/solr/VelocityResponseWriter#Using_the_VelocityResponseWriter_in_Solr_Core to see do you have all libraries in correct places.

Comment: New docs: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Response+Writers#ResponseWriters-VelocityResponseWriter